Animated Object with @GestureState shows console error "Invalid sample AnimatablePair"
I'm trying to get a "true" value when the user uses gestures to move the 300x300 rectangle and a "false" value when they finish interacting with gestures.
In this case it seemed logical to use @GestureState
As you can see in the .updating() call inside DragGesture I used @GestureState private var isDragging: Bool = false
@GestureState should change the opacity of the 100x100 red rectangle
 public struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var lastOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @GestureState private var isDragging: Bool = false
    
    public init() { }

    public var body: some View {
       
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
           
            Rectangle().fill(.red)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .opacity(isDragging ? 0 : 1)

            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                .offset(offset)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .updating($isDragging, body: { _, out, _ in
                            out = true
                        })
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            let currentOffset: CGSize = .init(width: lastOffset.width + value.translation.width, height: lastOffset.height + value.translation.height)
                            offset = currentOffset
                        })
                        .onEnded({ _ in
                            lastOffset = offset
                        })
                )
        }
        .animation(.default, value: isDragging)
    }
}


everything seems to work fine but when I add .animation(.default, value: isDragging) the console gives me this error while I use the dragGesture and the red rectangle opacity animation is running

Invalid sample AnimatablePair<AnimatablePair<CGFloat, CGFloat>,
AnimatablePair<CGFloat, CGFloat>>(first:
SwiftUI.AnimatablePair<CoreGraphics.CGFloat,
CoreGraphics.CGFloat>(first: -23.666666666666664, second: -19.0),
second: SwiftUI.AnimatablePair<CoreGraphics.CGFloat,
CoreGraphics.CGFloat>(first: 0.0, second: 0.0)) with time
Time(seconds: 0.0) > last time Time(seconds: 0.016666666720993817)

and I don't understand why... if I don't use animations everything works correctly otherwise it tells me this problem...
Where am I wrong? isn't this the right way to animate objects based on the use of gestures? are there other ways? is this the wrong way?

You don't use CropMask in your CropView, or is there a typo in CroxioMask.
Have you tried using @Binding var isInteracting: Bool in your CropMask with
CropMask(prefersShape: prefersShape, isInteracting: $isIteracting).

@workingdogsupportUkraine you're right it was a typo.. I modified my code...
Entering a @Binding causes the compiler to crash

Is it possible that there isn't a way to animate the opacity of a simple view when the user uses a gesture or not without constantly getting that error?

how come you have public struct CropView: PlatformView,
is PlatformView some sort of protocol? In any case, show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code. There
are too many missing parts to be able to compile and run your code to reproduce
your problem.

@workingdogsupportUkraine I modified my entire question using a very simple example.. The problem is always present.. I'm using public because I'm working on a package

I'm starting to think it's a console error that should be ignored... I've been trying to understand the problem for two days and I haven't found any solutions... as you can see, even in a very simple project with a few lines of code the error still appears... you can easily see by copying and pasting just the code I inserted in the question

I found that it helps to add animation to other state changes affected by the drag gesture. In your example, this means animating changes to offset too.
Here are two possible ways to solve:
1. Add .animation modifiers for other variables
For the example here, add a modifier for offset:
VStack(spacing: 40) {
    //...
}
.animation(.default, value: isDragging)
.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.1), value: offset) //  here

If you don't really want any additional animation then a duration of 0 seems to work. However, supplying nil as the animation type does not work and still reports errors in the console.
2. Perform changes using withAnimation
An alternative way to solve is to use withAnimation for updates performed in gesture callbacks, where these changes are not already  covered by .animation modifiers:
.onChanged({ value in
    let currentOffset: CGSize = .init(width: lastOffset.width + value.translation.width, height: lastOffset.height + value.translation.height)
    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.1)) { //  here
        offset = currentOffset
    }
})

As in point 1, a duration of 0 can be used, but an animation type of nil does not work and still reports errors in the console. Performing the changes using a Transaction with disablesAnimations = true also reports errors.

You were asking:

isn't this the right way to animate objects based on the use of gestures? are there other ways? is this the wrong way?

I would suggest, it is more conventional to use a GestureState for a value that is changing during the gesture, rather than for a boolean flag that signals that the gesture is happening. This avoids the need for an additional .onChanged modifier.
Here is how your example could be re-factored by using a GestureState for the drag offset. Things to note:

The boolean flag isDragging is derived from the drag offset (set to true if the offset is non-zero).

The animation modifiers are applied more specifically.

The callbacks for the drag gesture use trailing closure syntax.


public struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @GestureState private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero

    private var isDragging: Bool {
        dragOffset != .zero
    }

    private func combinedOffset(adding: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        CGSize(
            width: offset.width + adding.width,
            height: offset.height + adding.height
        )
    }

    public var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {

            Rectangle()
                .fill(.red)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .opacity(isDragging ? 0 : 1)
                .animation(.default, value: isDragging)

            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                .offset(combinedOffset(adding: dragOffset))
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.1), value: dragOffset)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .updating($dragOffset) { val, out, _ in
                            out = val.translation
                        }
                        .onEnded { val in
                            offset = combinedOffset(adding: val.translation)
                        }
                )
        }
    }
}


hi benzy and thanks again for your help... today I had to leave for work and I'll be back on Sunday. as soon as I get back I'll try to implement your suggestions to accept your answer I'm sure it will work... I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem for days... you always save my life
